# Meaning of. . . "it was hardly possible but what he should suspect"

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

[(From *The Wrecker* by Robert Louis Stevenson and Lloyd Osbourne, Chapter XIX, published 1892)](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Wrecker_(Stevenson)/Chapter_19)

Passage 290

> “Well, it's the other thing that has done that,” I replied. “It's all bygone now, all dead and buried. Amen! say I.”
>
> “I don't know that, Mr. Dodd; and to tell you the fact, I don't believe it,” said Nares. “There's more Flying Scud in the oven; and the baker's name, I take it, is Bellairs. He tackled me the day we came in: sort of a razee of poor old humanity—jury clothes—full new suit of pimples: knew him at once from your description. I let him pump me till I saw his game. He knows a good deal that we don't know, a good deal that we do, and suspects the balance. There's trouble brewing for somebody.”
>
> I was surprised I had not thought of this before. Bellairs had been behind the scenes; he had known Dickson; he knew the flight of the crew; **it was hardly possible but what he should suspect**; it was certain if he suspected, that he would seek to trade on the suspicion. And sure enough, I was not yet dressed the next morning ere the lawyer was knocking at my door. I let him in, for I was curious; and he, after some ambiguous prolegomena, roundly proposed I should go shares with him.

This sentence in bold puzzles me. I take it to mean 'it might be expected that he would suspect any cheat'. What does this sentence mean in actual fact? Is this sentence structure an ordinary one or is it obsolete? Especially the words 'but what' and their connection to the preceding clause trouble me there.

Comment: I thought you'd asked about this before. Writers from Stevenson's era sometimes used ***what*** where we use ***that*** today. And ***but*** for ***except***, so with a bit of rephrasing, the only possibility was that he should suspect (i.e. *He **must** suspect*, which is baldly restated immediately after).

Comment: It was **hardly possible** but [it was] **what he should suspect**. Was it hardly possible? Yes. Yet, was it what he should suspect? Yes.

Comment: Nevertheless, I don't really understand its meaning. What does the clause 'It was hardly possible' refer to? Is the speaker wondering in general or amazed that Bellairs is suspecting or does the speaker understand it as a logical consequence? What does the speaker express there actually?

Comment: @YosefBaskin: By *today's* standards we could parse the text as meaning the thing which he suspected was hardly possible. But I think Stevenson's text is an earlier version of English where the thing that's "hardly possible" is that he might *not* be suspicious - and he's bound to leverage his suspicions to his advantage.

Comment: *Kingcraft (king'kraf t), n. The art of governing; royal polity or policy. James was always boasting of what he called kingcraft; and yet it is **hardly possible** even to imagine a course more directly opposed to all the rules of kingcraft that which he followed.* (Thomas Macaulay) : This is from The Imperial Dictionary of The English Language by John Ogilvie and Charles Annandale, publication date 1885.

Comment: It seems a dummy "it", as in "it is necessary that...", "it is impossible that..."

Comment: I think *FumbleFingers* is right and s/he should write an answer, please.